# Xforms instance src attribute not working

Tags: xforms, xsltforms

I was trying to populate an instance based on a resource. However, the following doesn't seem to work. We are using XSLTForms (client side implementation of XForms).

```html
<xf:instance id="studentDetailsInstance" xmlns=""  src="http://localhost:8081/Restfultest/empDetails" />
```

I already checked the 'http://localhost:8081/Restfultest/empDetails' resource and it works fine and returns the correct XML document in the browser. Any idea on how to initialise the instance ?

If I try to load the instance from a local file as follows it works fine.

```html
    <xf:instance id="testInstance" src="empDetails.xml" />
```

I can even see in the developer tools network tab that a call is being made and even there is a response. Just that when I view the instance, the value is not set !!
I also tried to use the resource attribute but still instance value not populated.

Answer (score 1):

The cross-domain restriction does not allow the browser to get a file not located in the same domain unless the server is configured for this, for example with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`